# I want to write these cases of formula, but I don't know how

Tags: two-column, cases

This is the formula that I want to write, but I don't know how to do it.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Are you facing problem in putting them in two columns ? If so, it would be better to give a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/28557) of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Thanks. yes I have two problem.
first how to create two columns and second how to create that case (a) (i) , (ii).

Comment: `minipage`/`multicol` can create columns. And `enumerate` can do the numbering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses the `multicol` package and a bespoke `enumerate`-like environment called `myenum`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
   \newlist{myenum}{enumerate}{2}
   \setlist[myenum,1]{label=(\alph*)}
   \setlist[myenum,2]{label=(\roman*)}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{myenum}
\item  $a>0$ and $a\ge b$
  \begin{myenum}
  \item $Ma\ge Xa$
  \item $Ma<Ya$
  \end{myenum}
\item $b>0$ and $b\ge a$
  \begin{myenum}
  \item $Mb\ge Xb$
  \item $Mb<Yb$
  \end{myenum}
\end{myenum}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

An array with nested array will do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{array}{
  @{}
  l % label a
  l % condition
  @{\hspace{6em}}
  l % label b
  l % condition
  @{}
}
\text{(a)} & \norm{n_2}>0\text{ and }\norm{n_2}\ge\norm{n_1} &
\text{(b)} & \norm{n_1}>0\text{ and }\norm{n_1}\ge\norm{n_2} \\
 & \begin{array}[t]{@{}ll@{}}
   \text{(i)}  & \norm{M_a n_2} \ge \tilde{\kappa}\norm{n_2}, \\
   \text{(ii)} & \norm{M_a n_2} <   \tilde{\kappa}\norm{n_2},
   \end{array}
&& \begin{array}[t]{@{}ll@{}}
   \text{(i)}  & \norm{M_b n_1} \ge \tilde{\kappa}\norm{n_1}, \\
   \text{(ii)} & \norm{M_b n_1} <   \tilde{\kappa}\norm{n_1},
   \end{array}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,mathtools,enumitem}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item $\norm a  > \norm b$ and $\norm a  > \norm b$
\item[] \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
    \item $\norm a  > \norm b$
    \item $\norm a  > \norm b$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\columnbreak
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item $\norm a  > \norm b$ and $\norm a  > \norm b$
\item[] \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
    \item $\norm a  > \norm b$
    \item $\norm a  > \norm b$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}` taken from [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464748/28557).